# Are statements of arithmetic without logical negation or existential quantifiers decidable?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, peano-axioms

Consider the set of statements of arithmetic, such that:

- the statement contains no existential quantifiers, only universal quantifiers;
- the statement contains only logical `and` and not logical `or`; and
- the statement contains no logical negations.

For exact details of the language, see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16128/21034).

Is there a formal system that can decide the truth of all such statements, or does the incompleteness theorem guarantee that some will always be undecidable?

Comment: Well, the first thing to note is you can reduce the formula to a conjunction of universally quantified atomic formulas which we can attempt to decide separately. So the question is whether we can determine if one (multi-variate) polynomial with integer coefficients is or is not pointwise greater than another polynomial when viewed as functions of integers.

Comment: @DerekElkins thanks, that's helpful. Of course that then boils down to whether we can decide whether a single multivariate polynomial is greater than zero for all integer values of its variables. That *sounds* like it should be decidable, but I don't know straight away.

Comment: "The incompleteness theorem"  isn't the claim that a logic is incomplete.  It is much stronger than that.  "The incompleteness theorem" still applies to complete logics.

Comment: @DanielV in the comments we are discussing what would happen if you removed negation. For equality, what's wrong with `a<b+1 & b<a+1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're working in $\mathbb{Z}$ and your language consists of: variables, numerals such as 1, plus, times, minus, $\wedge$, $\forall$, and $>$. If this is correct, then your problem is undecidable, because we can inject the known-to-be-undecidable problem:

> Does the the multivariable polynomial $p$ have integer roots?

by squaring the polynomial and asking whether $\forall \vec x \;( p(\vec x) ^2 > 0).$

The undecidability of this problem is known as [Matiyasevich's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem), among other names.

Comment: A detailed exposition  of this theorem (suitable for students) was presented in American Mathematical Monthly, circa 1972.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the answer. (You are correct in your interpretation of the question.)